# In Oracle, how to use SQL to solve this program?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

[image]

I want output like this:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images, which are neither searchable nor accessible; instead, post this information as plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You need to find the adjacent rows -- which you can do by subtracting a sequence.  That is:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by trend, add_months(date, -seqnum) order by date) as new_trend
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trend order by day) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions as follows:

```
Select day, Row_number() over (partition by sm order by day) as trend
From
(Select t.*, Sum(case when trend = lg_trend then 0 else 1 end) over(order by day) as sm
  From
(Select t.*, Lag(trend) over (order by day) as lg_trend
  From yourtable t) t) t
```